# flexbox space betweeen div according to need

Tags: html, css, flexbox

hello I am having issue while create this navbar...because i cant space divs exactly s i want. please suggest some oher way to figure this out. 
and i have nothing to say more as i have included the image and code i have tried yet stackoverflow is asking me to add some more detail.

I am trying to create this navbar:

[image: iam trying to create this navbar]

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin:  0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.container .rightmenu{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {flex-grow: -1;}
div:nth-of-type(2) {flex-grow: 1;}
div:nth-of-type(3) {flex-grow: 15;}
div:nth-of-type(4) {flex-grow: 5;}
div:nth-of-type(5) {flex-grow: 1;}
.container li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: sans-serif-light;
  font-size: 14px;

}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.img{
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.img  img {
 width:44px;
 height: 44px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>jJio Nav Bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="imghome"> <a href="#"><img src="jio/home-white-icon.png" /></a>
   </div>
   <div class="leftmenu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">PLANS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DEVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">APPS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FIND A STORE</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="img"><img src="jio.png" /> </div>
  <div class="rightmenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SIGN IN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">QUICK PAY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>CART 0</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="imgsearch"><a href="#"><img src="jio/search-white-icon.png"/> </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: you show what you do, but not explane what you wanna get.. can you explane what you wanna fix in this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the `flex-grow` properties and edit your `img` class in this way

```
.img {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

your page will look like the image you included.

Hope this helps you.